# AVAudioPlayer makes my game look laggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

When I use AVAudioPlayers for sound effects in my game, they cause the game to look laggy. I'm not the only one facing this problem, but from what I've found on here/other sites they don't seem to come up with an answer to solve it. Therefore I'm asking once and for all... What can I do? I've tried to use prepareToPlay in the viewDidLoad, but it doesn't help.

Here's some code on how I use the AVAudioPlayer:

```
NSString *StartTap=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Tap" ofType:@"mp3"];
StartSound=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:StartTap] error:NULL];
StartSound.numberOfLoops=-0;
```

And then I call:

```
[StartSound play];
```

Comment: Since you mentioned it's a game, may I suggest another approach that might help. Try creating an `SKAction` property/ivar, initialise it in `viewDidLoad` to the following method `playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:` and use `runAction` at the appropriate times to play it. See if it works better now.

Comment: Does this work in a single view application?

Comment: I don't think so....Since you've said its a game, and haven't said otherwise, I've assumed it is Sprite-Kit. Any reason to why you are building a game in single view application?

Comment: It's a very simple game, so I figured I could make it as a single view application. The game is also finished, so I'd rather solve this audio problem than starting over from scratch in Sprite-Kit. Any other ideas on how I could solve it?

Comment: Where do you call the `alloc-init` of the `AVAudioPlayer`?, Try initialising it at load time, and only call `play` when you want to play the sound.

Comment: I call all of them in viewDidLoad. I suppose they have to buffer, and that's what prepareToPlay is meant for, but it doesn't work...